# Accessing the ASP.NET Cache from a Separate Thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

Normally i have a static class that reads and writes to `HttpContext.Current.Cache`

However since adding threading to my project, the threads all get null reference exceptions when trying to retrieve this object.

Is there any other way i can access it, workarounds or another cache i can use?

Comment: It isn't thread-safe.  Check out the lock keyword in your favorite C# programming book.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "since adding threading"?

Comment: @nobugz: `System.Web.Caching.Cache` **is** thread-safe.  No `lock` needed here.

Comment: @aaro: is the property thread-safe?  Doesn't look it.

Comment: @nobugz: `HttpContext.Current` is thread-local and read-only so basically, yes, it is thread-safe, although it's also wrong for the reasons pointed out by binarycoder below.  `HttpRuntime.Cache` is the same, but globally-accessible; it's not synchronized but it's also immutable, so you don't need to use any explicit locks.  In fact, the ASP.NET `HttpContext.Cache` is just a reference to `HttpRuntime.Cache`, so it has to be thread-safe, otherwise ASP.NET requests would steamroll each other constantly.

Answer (score 37):

The `System.Web.Cache` object itself is thread safe.

The issue is how to obtain a reference to it in a way that works throughout your application. `HttpContext.Current` returns null unless it is called on a thread that is handling an ASP.NET request. An alternative way to get the `Cache` is through the static property `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache`. This will avoid the problems with the `HttpContext`.

Comment: Oh cool, I don't know how I never came across HttpRuntime... +1, deleting my answer. :)

Comment: +1: This is the right answer. Here's some details: http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/archive/2006/02/06/437559.aspx

Comment: The pjohnson page has moved to http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/httpruntime-cache-vs-httpcontext-current-cache. The redirect doesn't work; took a while to find it with wayback machine.

Answer (score 2):

If your project is an ASP.NET project, then it was multithreaded even before you "added threading".

Check to see if `HttpContext.Current` is non-null before referencing `HttpContext.Current.Cache`.

Also, please post the complete exception you're receiving, and show us the code that references the cache.