# Accessing ASP.NET Caching from background thread

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, httpcontext

I'm writing an `ASP.NET MVC4` app that stores some security data in `HttpContext.Current.Cache.`

I then propose to use write a background thread to synchronise what's in the cache with the database. This provides a recovery path if my app has to be restarted.

So the background thread will do the following:

```
1.) Add new security tokens to the database.
2.) Remove expired security tokens from the cache.
```

So the cache needs to support read write access on background threads. It was my understanding that access to Cache was threadsafe, however does this remain so if I am using the cache from a background thread?

I understand that as I am accessing the Cache from a background thread I need to call:
`System.Web.HttpRuntime`.Cache as there is no current Request.

[Accessing the ASP.NET Cache from a Separate Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436681/accessing-the-asp-net-cache-from-a-separate-thread)

This question details something similar.

Thanks for looking, any answers gratefully received.