# How to cache in async services using IoC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asynchronous

I have a project where we use a service architecture, with Ninject to resolve our services. Nearly all our services use async.

Now, I want to add caching to a couple of the services.

I have never worked with caching in async methods, so I am unsure how to do it. I just know that I currently get this error as HttpContext.Current is null:

[image]

***So, what strategy should I go for to make this work?***

**My IoC setup: NinjectWebCommon.cs:**

```
 private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<Context>().To<Context>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<UserManager<User>>().To<UserManager>().InTransientScope();
            kernel.Bind<IUserTokenProvider<User, string>>().ToMethod((x) =>
            {
                var provider = OwinConfig.DataProtectionProvider;
                return new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(provider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }).InTransientScope();

            kernel.Bind<ICacheService>().To<HttpCache>();    
            kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
            // Lots of nice services

        }
```

My ICacheService:

```
public interface ICacheService
{
    object GetById(string cacheKey);
    object Create(string cacheKey, object obj);
    object Create(string cacheKey, object obj, DateTime expire);
    void Delete(string cacheKey);
    void DeleteByContaining(string containing);
    string GetCacheKey(string methodName, string value);
    bool ContainsKey(string cacheKey);
}
```

CacheService:

```
public class HttpCache : ICacheService
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (HttpCache));


        public object GetById(string cacheKey)
        {
            if (ContainsKey(cacheKey))
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey];
            }

            return null;
        }

        public object Create(string cacheKey, object obj)
        {
            return Create(cacheKey, obj, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(5));
        }

        public object Create(string cacheKey, object obj, DateTime expire)
        {
            if (!ContainsKey(cacheKey))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheKey,
                    obj,
                    null,
                    expire,
                    Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
            return GetById(cacheKey);
        }

        public void Delete(string cacheKey)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(cacheKey);
        }

        public void DeleteByContaining(string containing)
        {
            List<string> deleteList = new List<string>();
            HttpContext oc = HttpContext.Current;

            // find all cache keys in the system... maybe insane? I don't know lol
            IDictionaryEnumerator en = oc.Cache.GetEnumerator();
            while (en.MoveNext())
            {
                var k = en.Key.ToString();
                if (k.Contains(containing))
                {
                    deleteList.Add(k);
                }
            }

            foreach (var del in deleteList)
            {
                Delete(del);
            }
        }


        public bool ContainsKey(string cacheKey)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] != null;
        }

        public string GetCacheKey(string methodName, string value)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}_{1}", methodName, value);
        }
    }
```

My caller:

```
 public async Task<City> GetById(int id)
        {

            var cacheKey = _cacheService.GetCacheKey(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, id.ToString());
            if (!_cacheService.ContainsKey(cacheKey))
            {
                var city = await _db.Cities.FirstAsync(c => c.Id == id);


                _cacheService.Create(cacheKey, city);
                return city;
            }
            return (City)_cacheService.GetById(cacheKey);
        }
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Probably because I am stupid - there is a very high probability! Thanks for link

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov So, you say, if I use the System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache directly, I'll be safe? Please post an answer - you're also welcome to tease me for stupidity :D

Comment: Alternatively, use `System.Runtime.Caching`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The link you sent helped me. And I think that deserves to be an answer. Can you make an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HttpContext.Current.Cache` is one of several shortcuts to access ASP.Net global Cache object (another one for request lifitime is [Page.Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.cache.aspx)). If you need to access cache outside request use [HttpRuntime.Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy8zzs3(v=vs.110).aspx). (Also covered in [Accessing the ASP.NET Cache from a Separate Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436681/accessing-the-asp-net-cache-from-a-separate-thread))

Notes:

- Note that the fact you don't get `HttpContext.Current` could be symptom of bigger issue - you may expect code to run with `HttpContext` set but it is not, along with culture... Whether it is actually problem for you is open question, but at least check if you code does not unexpectedly use `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, `Task.Run` or schedule work on thread pool manually.
- While adding/reading single item from cache is thread safe be careful when you expect multiple entries to be consistent - you may need locking.
- Be careful not to put user-specific data in the cache, especially if your caching is at IOC level and you have no direct information whether result is user-specific or not.